# How to launch an Activity without a UI?

Tags: android

Is it in any way possible to launch an activity from the main function without having a UI? i.e. is there a way to create a sort of "wrapper" around another activity, i.e. by launching the main activity, it takes you to another activity automatically.

If that is not possible, is there a way to remove the main activity from the stack so that clicking the back button does not take you to a blank UI?
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class WrapperActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:555-1212"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to add the Intent flag,

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Or

call "`finish();`" after firing the intent.

Comment: I'm not sure that the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` trick will work here, because the `Activity` being started will be from another application. `finish()` should definitely work, though.

Comment: Added finish(); and Translucent.NoTitleBar to manifest.  Works like a charm.

Comment: @Vishwanath Intent basically not support finish(). can u detailed, where i can call finish and how?

Comment: You call `finish()` at the end of the Activity's `onCreate()` method, just before it returns.

Answer (score 137):

Android also provides a theme specifically for this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

Comment: This works well, but also causes the icon to disappear from the app drawer. To get the icon to appear, you'll need to use Brian515's answer.

Comment: I also found that this works, but if I display a progress dialog then it defaults to Holo.Dark which doesn't match the style of the rest of my app.

Comment: @LearnOpenGLES I'm using this theme and I still get the icon in the app drawer. I also find it to be a better option, since it sets a bunch of values to NULL, leading me to think that it is more efficient. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Comment: @AndyJohnson You can style your progress dialogs when you create them, so you could default it Holo.Light (or any other theme) if you want.

Comment: @LearnOpenGLES This question has nothing to do with the icon being in the app drawer, your link is broken, and setting values to NULL doesn't generally make things more efficient...

Comment: Do Not Forget to put `finish()` at the end, otherwise acts weird.

Comment: For this to work, your activity has to inherit from Activity, not AppCompactActivity.

Comment: @Kof: you can also just copy the contents of `Theme.NoDisplay` (only 6 attributes) to any extension of `Theme.AppCompat.*` in order to create your own `Theme.AppCompat.NoDisplay` that works with `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Its not work in 6.0 Marshmellow, Can you pleas provide solution for this version?

Comment: FYI, If anyone trying to set theme as "NoDisplay" on target version higher than 23, please revisit code once again. reference Link: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/02/psa-android-6p0-theme.nodisplay-regression.html

Answer (score 55):

In your manifest, when you declare the activity, use theme `"@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

Ex:

```
<activity android:name="yourActivityName" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you also need the app to appear in the app drawer.

Comment: This still opens invisible UI, which you have to press back before you continue using phone

Answer (score 15):

Just in case you are using Android 6.0+ or Target SDK is 23+, having a theme `android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` will lead to a crash with error `did not call finish() prior to onResume() completing`. This in fact is a bug recognised by Google developers [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151116170752/https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2353).

So it is recommended to use an activity with following theme as a workaround.

`android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

Comment: you can start a thread or runnable or service or whatever and call finish in onCreate

Answer (score 8):

I think this would help you a lot:

```
<activity  android:name = "MyActivity" 
          android:label = "@string/app_name" 
          android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow generally works in English; please make sure your post is as useful as possible to others by translating it.

Comment: When using this method make sure to pay attention to arunwithasmile's comment

Comment: Where would I put this?

Answer (score 7):

Using

```
<activity android:name="yourActivityName" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
```

mentioned by Brian515 works great.  This method is useful for creating an entry point Activity that decides on which activity to call, start, services, etc without having to show a UI to the user.  Remember to use `finish()` after you have started your intent.

Answer (score 5):

I am using `AppCompatActivity` and the solutions provided in this SO did not solve my problem. Here is what worked for me.

I added the following in my `styles.xml`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoDisplay">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoDisplay">true</item>
</style>
```

Then, for any activity that I want to disable the display, I modified like so:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".NoDisplayActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoDisplay">
```

Cheers!

Comment: you mean the androidmanifest.xaml file? I am not able to edit that file

Comment: That's weird. Care to post a new question?

Comment: I found out another way, but maybe later I'll ask a question bout it

Answer (score 3):

I had used `moveTaskToBack(true)` in `onResume()` to put the entire activity stack in background.

Comment: I had to use this method because I want the activity to show some times but not other times.

Answer (score 3):

In your manifest add `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` as mentioned in some of the answers above.

Also remove the `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);` line from your activity.java file.

Answer (score 2):

Looks similar to the question asked here: [Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

If it is, then you can use:

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

This should work to wipe activities off of the stack.

If you need to exclude from recent apps (long press home key) you can use this flag:

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS

Comment: This has nothing to with removing an activity from the history stack.

Comment: @Justin I'm quite sure that the question has this part: "If that is not possible, is there a way to remove the main activity from the stack so that clicking the back button does not take you to a blank UI?" Which I believe, is rather closely tied to the history stack, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: I apologize... I didn't notice the last two sentences in the question.  In any case, I don't think this solves the problem. I may be mistaken but I don't think either of these flags would remove the activity from the back stack (e.g. pressing the back button would still take the user to the blank UI)

Comment: @Justin, no, it doesn't take user back to a blank UI. This flag or the manifest equivalent will not add the activities to the stack, so there is nothing to go back to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interacting with the UI, what you are trying to do sounds more like an android service.

Comment: In some cases yes.... but not in all cases.  It seemed to be something that came up often-enough that the Android framework engineers created a specific theme for activities that don't have a UI.

Comment: If I use, for instance, a third-party library for selecting fonts or colors, it is typically designed to require the Activity that launches it to implement some callback interface.  But I may be launching the color picker from a popup window.  If I want to encapsulate the entire flow in the code for my popup window, rather than polluting my main Activity's interface, then I need a temporary (invisible) activity to act as the listener for the color chooser