# Avoid calling onPause() when there is no window focus

Tags: android, window, android-lifecycle, onpause, lostfocus

I'm designing an app for an Android device with NO SCREEN!
Naturally the problem is that I have no window focus (I have no screen)
hence onPause is called right after onResume.

For testing, I use a controlled PC with a simulated UI layout, but when I lose
screen focus or run without the simulated UI on my device, onPause is called.

I tried some window manager flags to help me but none of them helped me. Anybody tried an app without screen or can help?

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible to get your job done with an `Activity` but you would probably make your life unnecessarily miserable. I think what you are looking for is a `Service` or maybe a `BroadcastReceiver`. Check the official documentation on [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and [Broadcast receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: i thought about a server but it is my last choice for now because i have a hole complex app with meny classes,receivers,audios and recordings.

Comment: i'm looking for a solution to "trick" the android OS as if i'm allways on sceen

Comment: @Androidy I don't know if this is even possible. And even if it is, you're probably causing more problems than you solve. If you really want to stick with an `Activity` (which I don't recommend) maybe one of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704084/how-to-launch-an-activity-without-a-ui) will help you