# Android: Clear the back stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, stack

In Android I have some activities, let's say A, B, C.

In A, I use this code to open B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In B, I use this code to open C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

When the user taps a button in C, I want to go back to A and clear the back stack (close both B and C). So when the user use the back button B and C will not show up, I've been trying the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(intent);
```

But B and C are still showing up if I use the back button when I'm back in activity A. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 480, accepted):

Try adding [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) as described in the docs for [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

> This launch mode can also be used to
>   good effect in conjunction with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: if used to
>   start the root activity of a task, it
>   will bring any currently running
>   instance of that task to the
>   foreground, and then clear it to its
>   root state. This is especially useful,
>   for example, when launching an
>   activity from the notification
>   manager.

So your code to launch `A` would be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
CurrentActivity.this.finish(); // if the activity running has it's own context


// view.getContext().finish() for fragments etc.
```

Comment: Thanks but I've tried this. Still when I tap the back button after it shows C again. What can I be missing?

Comment: How do you declare your activities in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I've tried with android:launchMode="singleTop" but that didn't make any difference. I can't see what is wrong. So when you use this code and hit back button C will not show up?

Comment: Are all the activities declared with the same taskAffinity?

Comment: Huh, this doesn't work for me either. It should... I'll look into it.

Comment: Try it with `intent.addFlags(int)`, that made it work for me. I bet `setFlags` overrides the previous flags, so only `NEW_TASK` was getting added.

Comment: So irritating, I restarted the emulator and eclipse, cleaned the project and now it seems to be working just like you said. I mark this as the answer as this was the first one.

Comment: Glad I could "help". Restarting Eclipse and the emulator tend to be near the top of my troubleshooting list.

Comment: I have been frustrated with this for a couple hours now, with NOTHING seeming to work. I just realized that I am using Action Bar Sherlock SherlockActivities and not normal Android activities. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: @Kyle I struggled with this as well, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12468288/614880

Comment: doesn't work for me however calling finish() on source activity does what I needed to achieve

Comment: I had the same problem that this was not working. What fixed it for me was to call finish() after starting the new activity

Comment: @Arno Thank you!  finish() did it.  I would never have thought of it without your tip.

Comment: Use `addFlags` not `setFlags`, figured it out the hard way. Also added `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Comment: I also added one more clear
Intent intent = new Intent(SingUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

Comment: That's a good answer, but it may be replaced by without calling finish on current activity:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Also, for APK21+ there is finishAndRemoveTask.

Answer (score 184):

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: With all respect to the `CLEAR_TOP` flag - this combination is the ONLY one that completely cleared the entire stack and made the new activity the only one in the app. Thank you!

Comment: What's the diff between this and the accepted answer?

Comment: Thanks, the difference with the accepted answer is that with this flag we dont need to call activity.finish

Comment: With this setup, when I click back, it closes the app.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK worked perfectly together with NEW_TASK

Comment: This closes all activity in stack, WHAT I NEEDED. App closes on back press.

Answer (score 82):

What about adding in manifests file for related activity :

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

to the activity definition of B and C ? They will not be added to the backstack. Not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Be very careful while using this - If you are using login with FB or any similar sort of functionality

Comment: @Skynet Why? What are the problems associated with doing this?

Comment: When you pass control to FB for login from a page with nohistory as true, the FB app does not now where to land after loging the user in, in my case it was returning to the phone home screen and I almost lost my job!

Comment: This does not let an activity addded to backstack....this is not correct solution.

Comment: Exactly i am looking for

Comment: only this answer worked for me . because all of the sudden back button went to wrong activity . idk how . but this one . at least made me sure that no activity took place in stack

Answer (score 65):

This bothers me for a long time .Finally I worked it out by doing this:

In fragment,use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity,use(add one more intent flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` compared to fragment):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: If you are using androidannotations, you have to add: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Comment: Activity solutioin worked fine for me. Although I think with API 16 the solution from Daniel Schuler is easier.

Comment: Thank you yosafatade, that was what I was missing!

Answer (score 35):

Starting in API 16 (Jelly Bean), you can just call `finishAffinity()`.

Now you can also call `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(Activity activity)` with the compatibility library.

Be sure to set taskAffinity in the manifest to a package name unique to that group of activities.

See for more info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#finishAffinity%28android.app.Activity%29

Comment: Realy userful and easy solution if you are alread on API 16. Worked for me!

Comment: reminder: this will only work for activities in that share the same taskAffinity name

Comment: this only work if you have just one activity in the history.

Answer (score 31):

1. Add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the activity element in your manifest for Activity A
2. Then use `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`  and
   `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` when starting Activity A

This means that when Activity A is launched, all tasks on top of it are cleared so that A is top. A new back stack is created with A at the root, and using `singleTop` ensures you only ever launch A once (since A is now on top due to `..._CLEAR_TOP`).

Comment: Yes. this is what I'm using now but that doesn't do it. Still C shows up when I hit the back button.

Comment: Odd, I used that in a project and it works fine... pressing back takes me to the home screen. Perhaps there's something else going on. Could you post your manifest?

Comment: I restarted the emulator and now it seems to be working just like you said. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: singleTop should have nothing to do with clearing the stack.

Answer (score 19):

Try using

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

and not

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: This works. My assumption was that using `setFlags` would replace all default set flags but this was not the case

Answer (score 18):

If your application has minimum sdk version 16 then you can use 
 **finishAffinity()**

Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity.

This is work for me
In Top Payment screen remove all back-stack activits,

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
         finishAffinity();
        startActivity(new Intent(PaymentDoneActivity.this,Home.class));
    }
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity%28%29

Answer (score 10):

```
Use finishAffinity() to clear all backstack with existing one.

Suppose, Activities A, B and C are in stack, and finishAffinity(); is called in Activity C, 

    - Activity B will be finished / removing from stack.
    - Activity A will be finished / removing from stack.
    - Activity C will finished / removing from stack.
```

Answer (score 9):

As per [Wakka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453981/wakka) in [Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4376616/383414)...

---

Add `android:noHistory="true"` attribute to your `<activity>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 9):

For future research, try this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: These flags finally worked for me. What I did was I started the same Activity I was in with these flags and a boolean extra EXIT=true. The in onCreate() I checked the launch parameters for EXIT and called finish() if it was set true. That's a lot of hassle just to close your own app.

Answer (score 9):

Use finishAffinity(); in task C when starting task A to clear backstack activities.

Comment: only this answer works for me. Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK are not required

Answer (score 8):

Use this code for starting a new Activity and close or destroy all other activity stack or back stack.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 7):

I found an interesting solution which might help. I did this in my `onBackPressed()` method.

```
finishAffinity();
finish();
```

`FinishAffinity` removes the connection of the existing activity to its stack. And then finish helps you exit that activity. Which will eventually exit the application.

Answer (score 7):

In kotlin it is almost same like java. Only **|** symbol is replaced by **or** text.
So, it is written like-

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

Answer (score 5):

### Advanced, Reuseable Kotlin:

You can set the flag directly using setter method. In Kotlin `or` is the [replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45996002/974045) for the Java bitwise or `|`.

```
intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

If use this more than once, create an Intent extension function

```
fun Intent.clearStack() {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}
```

You can then directly call this function before starting the intent

```
intent.clearStack()
```

If you need the option to add additional flags in other situations, add an optional param to the extension function.

```
fun Intent.clearStack(additionalFlags: Int = 0) {
    flags = additionalFlags or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like you need to start `Activity C` from `Activity B` by using `startActivityForResult()`. When you click a button in `Activity C`, call `setResult(RESULT_OK)` and `finish()` so `Activity C` is ended. In `Activity B`, you could have the `onActivityResult()` respond by also calling `finish()` on itself, and you'd then be taken back to `Activity A`.

Comment: Yes, but if there are 42 activities between A and C, this will be rather tedious. The flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is supposed to do directly what the OP want.

Comment: This would be a less than optimal way of achieving what the OP wants, and as @Guillaume said, it would require code in all of the activities between the root and the top of the stack.

Comment: Duly noted. These are flags I need to learn about apparently.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answers here a little misleading because the code in the original question seems to work fine for me?

With A being the root activity, starting it from B or C only with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP does remove B and C from the back stack.

Answer (score 3):

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will not work in this case. Please use `(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)`

For more detail please check out [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all solutions and none worked individually for me.
My Solution is :

Declare `Activity A` as `SingleTop` by using `[android:launchMode="singleTop"]` in Android manifest.

Now add the following flags while launching `A` from anywhere. It will clear the stack.

```
Intent in = new Intent(mContext, A.class);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin example:

```
      val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
      intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
      startActivity(intent)
      finish()
```

Answer (score 2):

logout.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            logout.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 2):

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 2):

for me adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` solved the problem

```
Intent i = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, StartPage.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example to call your `Activity A` from `Activity C`

`Intent loout = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
loout.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
context.startActivity(loout);`

Answer (score 1):

you wont get any activity pressing back button after that :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finishAffinity();
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, you may try adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as well:

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`
`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Comment: That would only affect the activity at the top of the stack, not the root of it.

Answer (score 0):

The given code works correctly. I have tried in the Application Life Cycle sample.

I haven't got B and C in the back stack after starting activity A with flag, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 0):

i called `activity_name.this.finish()` after starting new intent and it worked for me.

```
I tried "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" and "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK"
```

But it won't work for me... I am not suggesting this solution for use but if setting flag won't work for you than you can try this..But still i recommend don't use it

Answer (score 0):

Add NO History Flag in the intent.

In activity B, start the activity C as below >>>>>>

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add this to your `Activity B` and `Activity C`

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

or `Override` `onBackPressed` function to avoid back pressing with a `return`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use setFlags() method for clear back side opened all activity close and start *yourActvity***

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with onBackPressed:

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(ImageUploadActivity.this, InputDataActivity.class);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ImageUploadActivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
   finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
private boolean clearHistoryBackStack = true;

@Override
public final void finish() {
    super.finish();

    if(clearHistoryBackStack)
        finishAffinity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me in kotlin:

```
 val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
 startActivity(intent)
 finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this may be coming late. I ran into this same problem while trying to move from activity A -> B -> C -> D, then to B if D returns true, I wanted to clear activity D and C.

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityUpload::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(intent)
```

I got the solution as described in the documentation.

> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

Answer (score -2):

This is a really old answer and i didn't really found a proper solution to it, to the sole purpose of clearing the backStack, i decided to create my own backstack, which is not even a stack tbh, but it doesn't have to be, since we want to clear everything in it anyways;

Theres an overhead of handlind the backstack everytime, but it gave me the control i needed;

---

First Declare a public static List of Activities (or fragments, whatever you need);

```
public static ArrayList <Activity> backStack = new ArrayList<>();
```

And inside all other activity's onCreate method:

```
MainActivity.backStack.add(this);
```

And finally, when you want to clear the backstack, simply call:

```
public static void killBackStack () {
    for (Activity ac : backStack) {
        if (ac != null)
            ac.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -27):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```