# Android: On Search Search Suggestion click every time Its opening new activity, Can we open the same activity the different data

Tags: android, search, onitemclick

I have implemented custom search suggestion, On suggestion click iam starting detail activity and showing data its fine, the problem is whenever i click on suggestion opening new activity for every suggestion.
eg: i have suggestions 
   Apple
   Ball
   Cat

When i click on Apple opening a detail activity with Apple data, and i have clicked on search again now Clicked on Ball and Opened detail activity with Ball data

When i click on back button it navigates back to Apple detail activity, So how can i avoid opening new Detail activity for every suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

Set `android:noHistory=true` on the `detail activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Note : this can only solve when back button is pressed, it won't back to your Apple detail activity. It's still opening new detail activity though.

Answer (score 0):

You want to control your back stack. [Here is an answer that should help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack)

Basically, when you launch your intent you can add a couple flags that should help.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Check [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29) for more info on the flags you can send in with your intent.

Good luck!