# Android clear the back stack if out of memory

Tags: android, memory

When running on Huawei G300 with Gingerbread, my app crashes after 5 minutes or so of usage during setContentView() as it runs out of memory.

Each individual page doesn't use much memory, but from some research it seems the memory accumulates in the back stack.

Following advice here, I've replaced all my calls to startActivity with a utility function that also calls finish().

[Android: Clear the back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack?rq=1)

This works; but there is no more back stack - the back button immediately quits the app, which isn't what I wanted.

Is there a way to only finish() the applications when I actually do run out of memory, and is that a reasonable approach to take?

Answer (score 0):

You should search for memory leaks. A good tool for that is [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) if you use eclipse. MAT is not that hard to handle and you can get quickly some very valuable information.

One of the most common mistakes I have seen on Android is to keep a reference on a context that is dead. For instance, having a singleton holding a reference on one of the activities you created. There is no real reason for an app to crash the memory if it is well coded.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Activity Manager was designed to manage this exact problem. The OS is designed to kill activities in the background and then restore them using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.

The fact that your app is accumulating memory usage over time indicates to me that you may have a Context leak somewhere (a static reference to a view, adapter, etc. that has a reference to a Context), or that you have a caching mechanism that's not adjusting to your memory heap, or some other situation that's causing the out of memory.

I highly doubt that it's the Activities in the Back Stack causing the Out of Memory.

Here's a great guide on tracking down memory leaks on Android:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Memory is a very tricky subject in Android.

Every app gets a heap memory limit depending on the device. This heap memory is the dalvik memory plus the native memory, and you can see it as the total column in the dumpsys meminfo results. The dalvik memory deals with everything except with the bitmaps, that are allocated in the native memory (this is true for Android versions before Honeycomb).

Having said that I can only answer to some of your questions:

As far as I know, Android will always allocate memory for Bitmaps, even if they are the same. Therefore, in your case, every activity allocates memory for your background.

I don't know if its better to work with themes, you'll have to try that.

On one hand, activities are not reclaimed while the device has enough memory to deal with the next activity. Every activity is pushed to a pile from where it is recovered when you pressed the back button. In case Android needs more memory it removes one activity from the pile deallocating its memory (going back to question number one, maybe this is the reason for not sharing memory). On the other hand, you can set the activities launchMode to change this behaviour (have a look here).

I think MAT doesn't show native memory data. Use dumpsys meminfo's native column to see how much allocated memory for Bitmaps you have.

I have had hard times dealing with OutOfMemory problems myself. Now I have a much more clear idea of how it works and I am able to work with large files without running out of memory. I would highly recommend these two resources that helped me a lot: