# Clearing the Launcher Activity from the stack

Tags: android

In my app, I have activity A (Launcher/Main Activity) ,B,C. A launches B or C depending on if the user is authenticated.

Now how do I remove A such that when the back button is pressed it just exits the app, not to A. Setting the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` doesn't seem to work.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed{
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish(); // finish activity B or C

    //also finish activity A
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to set

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

on A. You might also need to launch B/C with these Flags:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Finally, you can finish all activities under the current one in the task stack with the same affinity by calling:

```
finishAffinity()
```

For further information: [Android: Clear the back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack)

Comment: ah `android:noHistory="true"` did the job tnx