# Android Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK do not work from Dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog, back-stack

I don't want user to be able to go somewhere back from my LoginActivity.

This works nice from MainActivity (from Navigation Drawer):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Result - back stack is cleared.

But when I'm trying to call this from my custom Dialog:

```
private Context mContext;
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
dismiss();
mContext.startActivity(intent);
((Activity)mContext).finish();
```

back stack isn't clear, I can go back from my LoginActivity to previous window.

Tried to search the reason, but no result till now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to my `activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` did the work.

I took the idea from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack)

Comment: The same behaviour, no help. I suppose problem is that I'm calling all of this from my Dialog, but I cannot find the reason.

Comment: Does your MainActivity opens a dialog and then the dialog starts LoginAcitivity?

Comment: Yes, in dialog there is a SignOut button

Comment: It starts LoginActivity, but then returns to MainActivity, in spite of the fact, that I've finished it

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your activity stack:

Set `android:noHistory= "true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the `<activity` tag for the login activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_noHistory

Comment: It didn't work. Added this, but still pressing back returns me to previous screen.