# Android Navigation issue 3 screens

Tags: java, android, activity-stack

A is my main screen
B is an activity in my flow
C is an activity that user is taken to once he clicks on a link in B

I need user to be going like A - >B ->C

Now when I click back button on C I should be taken to A. However, when I click back once I reach A, C pops up.

I know it still exists in memory and I have tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP 
IT DOES NOT WORK FOR MY CASE.

I want all activities running in background to be destroyed once A's oncreate is called. How do I do that?

A has noHistory true
B DOES NOT have noHistory true
C has noHistory true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the Manifest of Activity A

From Activity C use:

```
Intent in = new Intent(mContext, A.class);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack)