# Open the new activity closing its forward one and without closing its previous one

Tags: android, android-intent

If I have various activities - A, B, C, D, E, F.

A opens B, B opens C, C opens D and so on like this A->B->C->D->E->F.

Currently I am at F activity after opening all the activities in backstack.

Now I want to go to B activity from F without closing A but closing all the activities(C, D, E, F).Please tell how to do this?

Comment: use finish() method to destroy classes that you don' want to put in backstack.

Comment: Use `intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Comment: see this [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack)

Comment: It's super easier with Fragment .

Comment: @Piyush This helped, thanks bro!!

Comment: when you don't require your activity to be in the backstack,just call finish for that activity that you don't want to be opened again.Use finish() after starting activity C>D>E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you'll have to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

```
Intent intent - new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

From the documentation:

> int FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
>
> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

1. Activity A calls B (Finish A activity)
2. Activity B calls C (Finish B activity) 
   Call A Activity using onBackPressed method in B activity
3. Activity C calls D (Finish C activity)
   Call C Activity using onBackPressed method in D activity
4. Activity D calls E (Finish D activity)
   Call D Activity using onBackPressed method in E activity
5. Activity E calls F (Finish E activity)
   Call B Activity using onBackPressed method in F activity

Comment: This will close all the class and start instance of new B activity.

Comment: Just a simple modification required as per user requirement. Don't finish class A and B as he wants them to stay in stack.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a MainActivity and multiple Fragments for these kinds of operations.

First, create a Fragment container (basically, a view that can hold a Fragment, you can change that Fragment anytime from your MainActivity).

Your XML layout for the MainActivity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then change the fragment in the container, in your MainActivity like this:

```
// Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
YourFragment firstFragment = new YourFragment();

// In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
// Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

// Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```