# How can I change Android theme in runtime without using recreate()?

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I'm already using *setTheme()* in onCreate() like:

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        data = Utility.GetTheme(this);
        if(data.isDarktheme())
            setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        else
            setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
...
```

So if I use recreate() in the activity:

```
switch_theme.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                   setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
                else
                    setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
                saveTheme();
                recreate();
            }
        });
```

My app freezes as I read in another question that it goes into an infinite loop.
Is there any way to fix this, preferably with keeping that setTheme() in the beginning of onCreate()?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#setDefaultNightMode(int)) for that you need to use the `DayNight` theme and on your clickListener you can do `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)` or `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)`

Here is a link that could help you: [Cannot switch between modes in DayNight theme dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724748/cannot-switch-between-modes-in-daynight-theme-dynamically)

Comment: Thanks but my custom themes are not really for daylight/evening use, mostly just different colours and i didn't come up with a better name for them.

Comment: Oh, then this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android) look at all the answers one might help you