# Remove all activities from Back Stack while calling a New activity

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Clear the back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack)

Is there any way to clear the back_Stack when I am calling a new Activity which not present in the back_Stack?(I am using Api vesion 8).. pls Help?

Comment: Here is the Link that will do the trick for you. [Back Stack Activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack)

Comment: similar to [Android: Clear the back stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794506/android-clear-the-back-stack) and [How to clear the Android Stack of activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190429/how-to-clear-the-android-stack-of-activities)

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing your precise requirements, it is difficult to give you an exact answer, but you can use *tasks* to achieve what you need. If you have 3 activities named A, B & C. If you set C to have a different `taskAffinity` to A & B in the Manifest, then a separate back stack is used for C. If you then set `clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` for A in the manifest, then the back stack will clear when the user leaves that task. So, app launch loads activity A. The user clicks a button which launches B. If the user now clicks back, they return to A. If from B the user clicks a button to launch C, then the back stack of the task for A & B is cleared, and if the user then hits back they are taken back to [A](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Affinities).

A full explanation of this can be found at [Handling Affinities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Affinities) and [Clearing the back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Clearing).