# Test Android's "destroy activity to save space"

Tags: android, memory

Because our app users report some crashes due to restored activities, I would like to test this.

Is there any possibility to manually cause Android to destroy the running (background) activity to save space?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "destroy", but how about `finish();`?

Comment: I just want to replicate android's behaviour (destroying background activities when too less memory is left) to *test* things. Not in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [official Dev Tools app](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-devtools.html) in the emulator, and if you get hold of a device running system level 4+, there's a system setting area labeled 'development' under which there's a checkbox for destroying activities as soon as they are paused.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clear the android stack of activities with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP?

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190429/how-to-clear-the-android-stack-of-activities)