# Clearing activity stack is not working

Tags: android

I have the following setup for my activities:

**A (noHistory) -> B -> C -> D -> E**

So when I start `activity E` from `activity D` I want `E` to become the root activity and clear the rest of the back stack.

I followed the solution mentioned in many posts here which is to add the following flags to my Intent:

```
final Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(this,
                E.class);
        explicitIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        explicitIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(explicitIntent);
```

However, `Activity E` (which was not running before) does not become the root of the back stack. Instead, just `Activity D` is deleted from the back stack, `C` and `B` are still there if I press the back button.

So is what I want to achieve really impossible in SDK < 11 as described here: [Clear the entire history stack and start a new activity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android) ?

Comment: You want to go to A from E on back press?

Comment: Check the below link, a similar question. It may help you.

[How to clear the Android Stack of activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190429/how-to-clear-the-android-stack-of-activities)

Comment: @Rasel No, I want to leave the application when I go back from E

Comment: call finish when going from one Activity to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just did as Rasel advised (in the comments to my question)
When entering activity E i called finish on activities B,C,D to get them off the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Start your activities like this..

**this in activity B**

```
 int k=1;
        Intent i=new Intent(B.this,C.class);
        startActivityForResult(i,k);
```

**this in activity C**

```
int j=1;
        Intent i=new Intent(C.this,D.class);
        startActivity(i,j);
```

**this in activity D**

```
 int j=1;
        Intent i=new Intent(D.this,E.class);
         startActivityForResult(i,j);
         setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
        finish();
```

**and put this in activity C**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode ==1) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
     finish();

      }
   }
```

**this in activity B**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode ==1) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
     finish();

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code just replace the below line:

```
explicitIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
explicitIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

with these line:

```
explicitIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Try this code.

Comment: Didn't work either (I guess because the activity E is not running yet)