# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP not closing all activities in the stack in android

Tags: android

I want to close all activities in th stack before going to new activity.

this is my code

```
Intent i=new Intent(first.this,secondsct.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
```

But this is not working. I have tried this earlier but not now. I dont know why. Can anyone know what may be the reason.

Comment: In your manifest file do you have defined `android:launchMode` with any value?

Comment: No. Should I have to set it for all activities

Answer (score 7):

I have tried Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP But haven't got proper solution so finally this helps me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

This clears all the stack and run only LoginActivity

Comment: In my case, this was the unique solution that worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`  in conjunction with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
```

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: Is there already an instance of the called activity (secondsct) present in the stack ? If you see the documentation about `CLEAR_TOP` it says >"If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent."

Comment: No there is no instance of secondsct in the stack.

Comment: Theres is a question that has been made with a similiar situation, see it over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940022/clearing-activity-stack-is-not-working

Comment: Still  not clear why it is not working. I have tried it in 2.1 it worked. now when in 2.2 it's not working

Answer (score 0):

use this function whenever u wanna exit. hope this will solve your problem

```
 public void exit()
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: here u can repalce the last line with the activity u wanna start with.. it will require a bit of modification

Answer (score 0):

I also tried all possible flags and I was invoking the `finish()` method just as you did. But I found a better way to end up all previous activities by using `finishAffinity()` method instead.

This solution is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities) in the third answer. And it solved my problem. Hope it solves yours.