# How to erase Activity stack in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, erase

I'm building a pizza order app. When the user adds an item to his cart, he is given an option to go to the item categories and browse/add new items. What I want to do is:

Main Screen > CategoryList(first appearance) > Pizzas in that category > Pizza Details > Shopping Cart > CategoryList(second apperance)..

I need to erase the Activity stack so that after adding an item to the cart, if the user touches the back button, he/she should go back to CategoryList(first appearance). "Pizzas in that category > Pizza Details > Shopping Cart" must be erased. If he/she touches back again, he/she should be at Main Screen.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to push the latest activity using  `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`
 or 
`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
see
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

So then you clear the stack of activities under your new activity.

Additionally you could try to override the back-event:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

see also
[Android: Clear Activity Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075349/android-clear-activity-stack)
or
[How to clear the Android Stack of activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190429/how-to-clear-the-android-stack-of-activities)

Comment: StackOverflow made me wait 4 minutes. sorry for the delay :)