# Finish all previous activities from other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

any one can help me with my task
I have one actvitiy where i open in new Intent new activity , and than in this new activiyt i open again new intent (previsios activities not close, so i can return to them when click back button on device).
I want write "exit button" and start new activity , i can close only one previsios activity, but pre-previsios is still open.
in ideal  its like - MainActivity - > SettingsActivity - > LogoutActivity(here we must back to loginActivity)
i was tried

```
 mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

but no luck with it  :(

Comment: use `finish()` method for removing the activity from stack and also update your question with good explanation and code snippet.

Comment: its work if only one activity was before, but i have 2-3 activities before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear the Android Stack of activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190429/how-to-clear-the-android-stack-of-activities)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this solution..

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
           Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
           Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

hope it helps.

Comment: For a better understanding for this, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344635/3968513

Comment: Worked for me as weel, but app makes a weird blank screen for a second.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     Intent intent=new Intent(currentActivity.this,TargetActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```