# How to close all activities and exit from an app

Tags: android, android-intent

My app is intended to allow only logged in user to access the activities. If a user logs out, the Shared preference boolean isLogged in is set to false and the user should not access the rest of activities except the LoginActivity.

However, I am able to access all the previously opened activities by pressing the back button.

I would use `finish();` while opening each activity but then I would like users to still use the back button while they're logged in.

I have tried solutions from other similar questions like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

and on the `onCreate()` of my LoginActivity I have added

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
         finish();
    }
```

When I press the logout option, the previous activity opens instead.

Any suggestions please help me?

Comment: try this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38268217/6334037

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this flags, that clear your TASK and create a new one

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Try this**

You need to add these flag in Intent..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        finish();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add all activity in array and when you want to remove just remove it from array and finish that activity. see my answer here [Remove activity from stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326642/how-to-remove-a-particular-activity-from-android-back-stack/38326848#38326848)

Answer (score 0):

I faced to a similar situation. As I figured out, even if I call the `finish()` function in the beginning, the whole `onCreate()` function get executed. Then it will finish. In my scenario, in the `onCreate()` function, I call to another Activity. So even if the main activity finishes after `onCreate()`, the second activity still exists. So my solution was,

`private boolean finish = false;`

in onCreate() of the main function,

```
if(intent.getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        finish();
        finish = true;
    }
```

and I put a check in all navigations

```
if(!finish) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

My exit function was,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To exit the app when back button pressed try to use following code also:

```
finishAffinity();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).