# Android: remove activity from stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a database tree structure in the backend of my application.
It basically looks like the following:

```
List
  |- View
```

I wrote the functionality to transform a View to a List displaying the View. Shown in here:

```
List
  |- List
     |- View
```

When triggering the `toList()` function the Application should rebuild the structure in the database, and switch to the new List Activity displaying the list content.

All of the above works, except one thing:

When switching to the new List Activity the previous View should be removed from the stack in order to keep the order when pressing the 'back' button.

I tried with the following intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ViewActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
// new_item is a DTO containing the needed id to create the List activity
i.putExtra("selected_item", _new_item);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PostActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

as well as:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ViewActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
// new_item is a DTO containing the needed id to create the List activity
i.putExtra("selected_item", _new_item);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PostActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

which both didn't work as expected.

Is there any other method of maybe using `finish()` with the above intent?
I explicitely don't want to start the activity for a result.

Comment: that`s what a answered in this questions, take a look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374297/how-to-close-all-activities-and-exit-from-an-app/38374433#38374433

Comment: That does not work the way it should. If I press the back button after going to the new ListActivity the application closes. It seems that the whole stack is cleared, not only the ViewActivity

Comment: Sorry man, i will write here what you can do

Comment: does it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a finish() at end of your code and remove the flags, this will destroy the ViewActivity and it will be removed from your stack!

```
Intent i = new Intent(ViewActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
// new_item is a DTO containing the needed id to create the List activity
i.putExtra("selected_item", _new_item);
PostActivity.this.startActivity(i);

finish();
```