# Dynamically Specify the First Activity

Tags: android

The main activity is specified in AndroidManifest.xml with:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But I don't know how to dynamically specify the first activity according code logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify a default Activity which contains the logic to start whichever Activity you want within its onCreate method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // CODE HERE TO CREATE INTENT
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[@Ian G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4420189/383414) is correct - but I think his can be improved by removing the launch activity from the backstack. This is what [@gardarh is trying to say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8924771/383414).

I have a full answer at this related question that basically shows both sides of the problem, activity code & manifest code:

- [Conditionally set first activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17477194/383414)

The activity code is basically the same as @Ian's, so I won't repost that. But I will include my addition to his answer.

---

Manifest Declaration (note the `noHistory="true"` parameter):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.EntryActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I don't have points to add comments but the removing the launcher activity from the back stack might be useful in some cases. This SO post explains how to do this:
[Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)