# Android activity stack question

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

I've 1 question for the Android stack and the push stack process as stated below:

A->B->C->C->C->C->D

C will be repeatedly call itself until certain condition met.

i use the code below to start activity.

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

My problem is after activity D started i want straight away go back to activity B instead of go back activity C when press the back button.

A->B->C->C->C->C->D  -----> A->B

I know i should use intent setFlags but i've no idea what to use
http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Edited: 
For this case Activity C is question page and the Activity D is the result page.
A->B->Question 1->Question 2-> Question 3 -> Result.

I need to keep the history stack b4 activity D, this will allowed user to change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

for activity: c: 
try intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion. I've edited my question. I need to keep the history b4 it reach activity D.

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion. I've edited my question. I need to keep the history b4 it reach activity D.

Comment: maybe u can try keep serveal C states into a single activity?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) each time you call startActivity() with the intent for B.

This will bring B to the top, popping all activities that were on top of it.

Comment: I need to set the flag at A->B or B->C?

Comment: i set the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when activity B start activity C but no luck, when i press back button at activity D i stil go back to activity C.

Comment: set it when you are re-starting B after you've already pushed all your C's.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent i = new Intent(ACTIVITY_D, ACTIVITY_B);     
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);        
    startActivity(i);
    return;
}
```

Override the `onBackPressed()` and set the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag. Place the function above under your activity D.