# Remove "start"-activity from the history

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

I am looking for a solution to remove the StartActivity from the history stack. 
The StartActivity is the one that is being started at the beginning. I am using this Class to check some user values and want to redirect the user to the MainActivity if all is correct.

I have tried to set a flag:

```
addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

but this does not do what it should.

```
App starts -> StartActivity -> MainActivity -> PRESS back -> the app should end
```

it does:

```
App starts -> StartActivity -> MainActivity -> PRESS back -> StartActivity
```

Thank for your help!

Edit: This is the code i am using to start the MainActivity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, DashBoardActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: could you please post your code to switch between activity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` when starting StartActivity to achieve described behaviour.

The same you may achieve if you set `noHistory` attribute to `true` in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: note: this method doesn't work if you try to use a login provider like facebook (which launches it's own activity and then returns you back to your start activity afterwards)

Comment: That's my situation, any tip how to deal with that ?

Answer (score 19):

You can simply call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) after you start the MainActivity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, DashBoardActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: And of course this approach works as well, but when he mentioned removing from the history, flag was first that came to my mind.

Comment: Yes, your solution might be the proper way to archive it. My one is more the quick and dirty one. ;)

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. But the other solution @Zelimir seems to be more elegant.

Comment: thanks, it wasn't immediately clear from the docs that you need to pass `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and ALSO call `finish()`