# Clear the stack activity on Back button pressed

Tags: java, android

I have 4 activities:

```
Menu -> screen 1
Menu items -> screen 2
Detailed View -> screen 3
Ordered item -> screen 4
```

In Menu activity(screen 1) I have a button onclick of that it goes to MenuItems activity(scrren 2 which is List view), on click of any item in the list view it to corresponding item detailed view in this activity(screen 3) I have a button called ordered view, onlclick of this it would go to Ordered item(screen 4), in this scrren 4 I have a button which will go to screen 2.

This is the flow

```
Screen 1 ->screen 2->screen 3->screen 4->screen 2
```

Prob: after doing the basic flow now when I click on back in screen 2 it goes to screen 4 and again clicking on back it goes to screen 3 which is resulting the user to click back button n no of times since the activity already exists in stack.

How to handle this I mean back button navigation.

I have tried using flags in intent but it's not working for me.

I have also referred this

1. [Android: Remove a series of Activites on clicking back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802089/Android-remove-a-series-of-activites-on-clicking-back)
2. [On logout, clear Activity history stack, preventing "back" button from opening logged-in-only Activites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007998/on-logout-clear-activity-history-stack-preventing-back-button-from-opening-l)

**edit I got the answer:**
so as few of my friends have answered here I used this 
**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**

So

```
screen 1->screen 2->screen 3-> screen 4->screen 2
```

So in screen 4 I have to set this flag so that it will clear all the activities above that activity.

Comment: did you try overriding the `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: @Pallavi do you mean in that method call the intent?

Comment: Are we to guess what the code you've tried looks like?

Comment: @Simon in that case i have paste the code of all the activities...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, screen 1.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use finish() after every intent so this activity will be close.

The you can intent function from 4 activity to 2   activity . Also use finish after it.

Comment: correct but there is a prob in that suppose 
screen 1->screen 2->screen 3-> so if i call finish() each time, then form screen 3 if i click back it should go to screen 2 instead it wil exit from app as there will be no activities in stack.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is set screen 2 to have launchMode singleTop in the manifest. This ensures that there is only one of those activities in your stack at one time.  You also want to set the clear top flag in your intent.

```
Intent a = new Intent(this,A.class);
a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(a);
```

Comment: hey can you please explain what this will do?

Comment: the clear top flag clears activities on top of the activity you're launching to.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use finish() after every intent so this activity will be close.

The you can intent function from 4 activity to 2   activity . Also use finish after it.

http://nanostuffs.com/Blog/?p=607

u have to check the link in this link uses a child activity  for a main activity for tab .