# when the user click home key and then touch my application icon i am getting login scren instead of user home screen

Tags: android

I am having  many activity in my application.

Consider very first screen I show is login screen after successful login I will show another activity which  will be the user home screen.

My question is when the user click home key and then touch my application icon I am getting login scren instead of user home screen.

Deatils.

LoginScreen launchMode is "singleTask"

action `android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"`

category `android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"`

User Home screen launchMode is "singleTask".

Comment: Check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790973/remove-start-activity-from-the-history/5791306#comment-6639338

Comment: But when i click home key my home screen activity should be in onPause state and when i click home key it should resume but after using nohistory i am still getting my login screen and thwn when i pres back i am getting home screen. what to do

Answer (score 0):

Check in the onResume() method of your login activity if the user is already logged in. If he/she is already logged in then start the next activity and call finish() on the login activity.

I would always pass the action flow through the login activity, so you have a central point where you can check whether the current user is authenticated properly.

Comment: hi, finally i got it by removing login screen launch mode singletask. And also can u type shortly the launch mode usage.