# How to manage activity stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

When my stack is in this situation:

```
A->B->C
```

if I start D activity, I want that the activity stack becomes:

```
A->D
```

Note that activity C is a dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here are the steps which will do the needed:

- from activity C launch the activity A with a boolean `fromActivityC` bundled with the intent and the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` set .
- Now in the on create of the activity A check for this boolean "fromActivityC" first and if present launch the activity D else the normal flow continues.

  ```
  // following code can be used to get the boolean in the oncreate
  boolean entrypoint=this.getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("fromActivityC");
  ```

A lil workaround but Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, interesting trick, it runs ... But typing on keyboard I had an idea: when A calls B, finish A; when B goes back, recreate A; when C calls D, create D with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. Yessss!!

Comment: yes that should work .. but dont you think re creating activities like this everytime will take a lot of cpu cycles and defeats the very purpose of the activity stack..something to ponder upon :)

Answer (score 2):

There is several way to remove a activity from the stack or prevent it to be stacked :

To remove your activity from the stack , simply call `finish()`, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

You can also implement in your manifest the property : android:noHistory="true" which prevent an activity to be stacked.

See this question form more detail : [Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

Answer (score 1):

A little hacky, but you could start activity A while clearing the stack, then start activity D.

Activity A **might** appear for a moment before disappearing though

Answer (score 1):

You could try finishing `ActivityB` when you launch `ActivityC` and the same in `ActivityC` when launching A.

Your code would look like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this.class.ActivityC);
startActivity(i);
ActivityB.finish();
```

Comment: I can't, activity C is a dialog. If I finish B when I start C I see A under C.

Answer (score 0):

on callback of C ,  pass a message back to A and start your D from Acall finish , this will finish B and C (because C is apart of B).

Answer (score 0):

here is a better solution not depending on evaluating the `Intent` content in `A`:
use the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME`

you should also take a look at the other flags [Android Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)