# Create intent with different context

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to create an intent other than (THIS, myActivity.class)?
I'm asking because I'd like to create an intent so that when the user goes to the other activity and presses 'back' button, he goes back to a activity other than the one where I created the intent.

Such as:

A creates B, B creates C, user presses 'back' on activity C, goes back to A.

I've tried new Intent(myOtherActivity.class, myNewActivity.class) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things is this question:

1. You can start an [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) with different approaches, but it is always implemented using an  Intent. So see the [Intent system](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more information
2. If you want to start a different activity different then previous when using the back button, then you should [manage the activity stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369918/how-to-manage-activity-stack).

I hope this clears somethings up! if not comment below.

Answer (score 0):

```
myOtherActivity.class
```

is not a context but a class, so you need to have to give an actual instance of an Activity class - I think :-)

Comment: Please take a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context, java.lang.Class<?>)