# android activity back stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 5 activity in back stack. At a time, I want to remove 4 child activity from back stack. how can I do this? i dont want to finish each activity by hand. is there any method which can make my back stack empty?

Comment: Have a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start your fifth activity with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag.

Comment: the flow of activity is  A -> B -> C -> A -> B -> C -> A . whenever i come back to activity A i want to finish all other activity. is FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP work? if yes then please let me know the syntax. thanks

Comment: Assuming you are in Activity C, if you now start Activity A like this: `Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class)  .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   startActivity(intent);` Then all activities but A are killed as soon as A is started.

Comment: is there any way to finish all activity in activity A?

Comment: Afaik there is no method like `clearActivityStack()` to clear the whole stack from a certain activity, if you mean that. You can wether clear the history on launching a new activity with the flag like already mentioned or you can end the activity manually by calling `finish()`. Also take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) reference, it countains all available flags and methods for handling activities.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is essentially being able to end application from any other activity different from the first one.

What I do is using an application variable determining if application must be shutdown and then check it on the onresume method.

```
protected void onResume()
{
        super.onResume();
        if (!getMyApplication().isPlatformActive())
        { 
              /* We finish every activity after resuming if we must shutdown application */
              finish();
        }
}

boolean isRootScreen()
{
        /* Every activity will override this and set it to true if want to exit application from here */
        return false; 
}

protected void onBackPressed()
{
        if(isRootScreen())
        { 
            /* You could show a confirmation dialog here */
            getMyApplication().setPlatformActive(false);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```