# Android stack clear without calling another activity

Tags: android

How do I clear the stack without starting another activity? I tried

```
testIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(testIntent):
```

But it requires me to start another activity. Is there any other way? Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing an activity from the history stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this post: [Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

That may or may not be helpful.

You can add a `android:noHistory="true"` to your `<Activity />` in `AndroidManifext.xml` or you can use the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG%5FACTIVITY%5FNO%5FHISTORY) when calling your activity.

Without knowing exactly why you need this functionality, I can't offer any suggestions on how to implement. Maybe you can find a way to reorganize your app so that you can take advantage of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually keep track of every activity that is running in your application and call finish() on each one of them.