# blocking the activities once they are executed in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on an application which contain register activity as it's first page which is on tabs. i want that once the user is register then whenever the user starts the application it should always run from main menu screen and should never display the register screen till the user uninstall the application and reinstall it again.

Comment: use sharedpreference to maintain flag value..look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9964744/603744

Comment: you should use [android-activity] tag instead of [activity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SharedPreferences. This is an example:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
editor.commit();
```

So you can check if firstTime is true doing this:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(mPrefs.getBoolean(firstTime, false){
    //show screen
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replies...can you please tell where exactly do i put this SharedPreferences code??

Comment: You can put this code in your Activity entry point, the first Activity you reach when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

Set your AndroidManifest to start the MainActivity as the default activity.

Then in the `onCreate` check if the user has registered (perhaps store this in `SharedPreferences`), if they have NOT registered - instantly start the intent for your RegisterActivity, otherwise carry on as normal.