# How to Skip the first activity under a condition

Tags: android

I'm building a group of apps as a package similar to MS Office. Here each app has its own launcher as well as it can be launched from inside the home app. Each app has a login page. I need to display the login page when the app is launched from android launcher and not showing login page while launch from home app, How can i achieve this?

My scenario:

From Launcher----->(App)Login page--->(App)Home screen

From Home app----->(App)Home screen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that by launching an empty `activity` (with no UI) and in its `OnCreate` method depending on some variable information (You can use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) perhaps for that purpose) you can decide which `Activity` to start (Login or Home Screen app).

PS:

Btw if the login always leads to the same activity (Home Screen and is not used to login somewhere else) you don't even need the empty activity, you can check this in the `Oncreate` method of the login activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (logged_in_check_is_true)
       { 
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
          this.startActivity (intent);
          this.finishActivity (0);
       }

    ...
```

Comment: Thnx :) just now it struck my head that shared prefs can be accessed from other apps :)

Comment: Not if they are "MODE_PRIVATE"

Answer (score 1):

You should always start `LoginPageActivity`. But if you start it from  your "home app" just pass special extra to activtiy:

```
public class LoginPageActivity extends Activity {
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean needLogin = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("need login extra", true);
        if (!needLogin)
        { 
            // start your home screen
        }
        //setup login page
    }
}
```

In home app just pass "need login extra" as false.

Answer (score 1):

Basically similar to what tozka said yet you can also launch the activity you expect to be more often required and onCreate you check if you are in the right activity. If not call startActivity with the other activity without inflating any views etc before. So if your expectation is right then in more than 50% of the cases you are already in the right activity saving your app from two activities being called when it is launched