# Show login activity only once and on next start main activity

Tags: java, android

I want to open login_activity on first time entering app, and then on the second entering to app open main_activity.

I create something but it wont work. so I wonder what I'm doing wrong?
this is my LoginActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        userPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userPhone);
        loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

        dbHandler = new LogsDBHandler(this);

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        setTitle("AMS - biomasa | prijava");

       SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
            edt.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
            edt.commit();
        }
    }

    public void insert() {
        User user = new User (
                userName.getText().toString(),
                userPhone.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addUser(user);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Prijavljeni ste!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == loginBtn && validateUser()) {
            insert();
        }
    }
```

In main activity i have only image and two buttons.
And in manifest I add launcher to main and login activity.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display login screen only one time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964480/how-to-display-login-screen-only-one-time)

Comment: use sharedprefrence...put flag on successful login in it and each next time check flag and load activity accordingly

Comment: you should remove the launcher in mainActivity, and I also have a doubt, you are assigning true on the value even if the user didn't click login, but it's a detail.. anyway kevz answer is the best i think

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Create one start-up activity call it as SplashActivity

   ```
   public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

   // decide here whether to navigate to Login or Main Activity 

       SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       if (pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           finish();
       } else {
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           finish();
       }
   }

   }
   ```
2. In your LoginActivity simply set `activity_executed` to `true`

   ```
   public void insert() {
       User user = new User (
           userName.getText().toString(),
           userPhone.getText().toString());
       dbHandler.addUser(user);
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Prijavljeni ste!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   //set activity_executed inside insert() method.
   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
   edt.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
   edt.commit();

   }
   ```

change manifest as below-

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />

<activity android:name=".SplashActivity" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: This is good but somehow it always opens me LoginActivity when I'm entering the app. Could you possibly know why is this? Or I do something wrong..

Comment: @RubyDigger19: The First activity with Launcher "Intent Filter" is started. In your case it should be MainActivity and not LoginActivity. Is the sequence correct i.e MainActivity then LoginActivity in manifest file?

Comment: I did everything you say. Even when I put MainActivity to open first it doesn't open before that LoginActivity. But when the LOginActivity is the first, it opens it every time when I'm entering the app.

Comment: @RubyDigger19: would u like to talk about it in chat? Here is the link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105212/show-login-activity-only-once-and-on-next-start-main-activity

Answer (score 1):

you can change launcher activity as **main activity**.so that when you open the application it is starting from **main activity** there you can check whether he is logged in or not.if he is not logged in you must navigate him to **login activity** or else you just do it as it is.Following is manifest file..

`<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>`

Answer (score 0):

You should add another empty activity (with no UI) that loads before anything.

Then use `SharedPreferences` to store some value. Thus if the user has already opened your app once, the value is stored. And then use a condition to check this value. If its the value you saved skip `login_activity` and direct to `main_activity` else direct to `login_activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem about the line

```
if (pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)) {
```

You can Implement this method to call inside if(appIsLoggedIn)

```
public boolean appIsLoggedIn(){
      return pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false);
}
```