# How to clear backstack when going to a new Activity in API <= 10

Tags: android, api, android-activity

I have an application that has a startup flow like this:

**StartupActivity -> LoginDialog -> LoginActivity -> HomeActivity**

When I go from the LoginActivity to the HomeActivity I call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this, HomeActivity.class );
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB )
{
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
}
else
{
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
}
startActivity( intent );
finish();
```

`On >= API 11`, this makes it so that the `HomeActivity` is a brand new task and the `StartupActivity` is no longer on the back stack.

However, on `API <= 10`, the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` clears the `LoginActivity` from the back stack, but the `StartupActivity` is still there. If the user clicks back from the `HomeActivity`, it takes them back to the `StartupActivity`.

*How can I clear the StartupActivity from the back stack?*

- From my research, it seems like the best way is to startActivityForResult() but can I do that from the Dialog? Who will get the result?

**Summary**:

- From the `StartupActivity`, I show the `LoginDialog`.
- From the `LoginDialog`, I go to the `LoginActivity` without clearing the back stack.

  - This is because I want the user to be able to go back from the `LoginActivity` to the `StartupActivity`.
- From the `LoginActivity`, I go to the `HomeActivity` and clear the back stack
- Pressing back still goes back to the `StartupActivity` on `devices <= API 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it...

When the LoginDialog starts the LoginActivity, I can use startActivityForResult() to make the LoginActivity pass back a result to the StartupActivity. If the result is a successful login, I can finish the StartupActivity.

The LoginDialog can be triggered from multiple places, but I can set a flag if it's triggered from the StartupActivity in order to call startActivityForResult().

The thing I was stuck on was how to use startActivityForResult from a dialog to get the result back into the activity that launched the dialog... and I figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Add following in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

for all the activities which you want to remove from backstack. You must put it inside the `<activity>` tag.

Or just call finish on StartupActivity as soon as you start a new activity.

I would suggest you the first option as its a right way to do it.

Cheers.

Take a look at this answer -> [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work because I *do* want history for the StartupActivity. I want you to be able to go back to it from the LoginActivity, but I don't want you to go back to it anymore after you successfully get to the HomeActivity.