# Disable Stacking the Activities When Pressing the Home to Navigate

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have setup the home button as enabled `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` everything is fine I just want to disable the stacking of the activities, so that when I press the back button while I'm on my MainActivity the app will exit instead of going back to the previous activity. 
This is happening because I'm navigating through the home button. 
I tried adding `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` but it's the same result.

Any suggestions on how to disable the stacking?

Comment: Did your read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack

Comment: No, :/ I guess I was using the wrong keywords for the search criteria, I focused more on the fact that I'm using Sherlock, thought that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this in your `manifest

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

so that the `Activities` aren't kept on the stack. You can do this for certain `Activities` if you want. Alternatively, you can use the `Intent Flag`

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
```