# Android SearchView and backstack

Tags: android, back-stack

My android app use a searchview in actionbar, for some queries i don't want it to be included in the back-stack, is that possible? FYI, i've tried by setting intent flag to FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY/FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP inside onNewIntent() but with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried to disable adding SearchView (as MenuItem) by sending a flag in the bundle so you'd know when not to show the search item, when the activity is resumed/new intent?

Comment: i need the searchview to always available in actionbar, but on some query i will direct to another activity and in this case i want the query to exclude from back-stack.

Comment: found my answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)