# SlidingMenu clear activity stack

Tags: android, menu, slidingmenu

I'm developing an application using SlidingMenu library.

Every activity has a sliding menu. So when I start every next activity from side menu, I have a history stack:

A => B => C => D

But I want to have next behavior.

Let's imagine that I have activity A. Then I start Activity B from Side menu A => B. But if I start activity C from side menu I want to have A => C, not A => B => C. So when I click back on activity C i can return to activity A.

How to accomplish such behavior? (Linkedin android app has such behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is very similar to the question asked here and should help you out:

[Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)