# Activity LauchMode within a Login Behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

I'm trying to understand the `android:lauchMode` in order to apply it properly to an App I'm working on. Basically I have 2 activities. `LoginActivity` and `HomeActivity`.

The session state is stored, so if the app is killed and you were logged in, next time you open, you will be still logged in. So, keeping that in mind, the behavior I'm looking for is the following:

You always launch the on `LoginActivity`, it checks if you're logged and if `true`, then it directs you to `HomeActivity`. While in `HomeActivity` if you log out, it will redirect you to `LoginActivity`.

What I need is that either way if you are in Login or Home activities, the back stack will be clear and if you press the back button, or whatever, you will not be redirected from Home to Login or Login to Home, but instead the app might close.

**EDIT:** I can't use `noHistory="true"` in the `Manifest` because the Auth method should return to the `LoginActivity`. Only `HomeActivity` should not be allowed to go back to `LoginActivity`. So, is this a proper solution?

```
Intent login = getIntent()
login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent home = new Intent(this,Home.class);
startActivity(home);
```

Answer (score 1):

Flag the login activity as no history from the manifest or in the intent. If they press back the app should close. If they press log out create a new login activity intent and finish the home activity.

**See:**

[Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

Comment: Well there is a problem, I can't use noHistory on Login cause: The idea is that the user cannot come to Login from Home, BUT the auth method (FB auth) needs to come back to Login