# How can I call activity to second stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activitys, A ,B1, B2, B3, B4, C, D, E

When my stack is 
A->B1->C->D.

Then I call B2 from D ,activity stack need to like this 
A->B2.

Bx will always set to second history in stack .

How can I set activity_flag in Activity D ?

Comment: if B2 parent activity is always A then you can set it as such I think in manifest then all you have to do is clear stack on opening B2.

Comment: Also some useful stack answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack?rq=1)

Comment: Do you mean using "android:parentActivityName" in all Bx activity ? ok I will try try  :)