# Android app crashes without any exception, when trying to sign in with Google plus

Tags: android, debugging, google-api, google-play-services, android-memory

I'm developing an app, which has a LoginActivity with a Google plus sign-in button.
I've already Enabled the Google+ API in Google's api console and made an Oauth account.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

**activity class declaration:**

```
    public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
            ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, PlusClient.OnAccessRevokedListener {

  private PlusClient mPlusClient;
  private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
  private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 2
```

**onCreate:**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity").build();
```

**onClick:**

```
     public void onClick(View view) {
        Utils.LOGD("onClick - View = " + view);

        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
            Utils.LOGD("onClick  : mPlusClient status  = " + mPlusClient);
            if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
                Utils.LOGD("onClick - mPlusClient is connected");
                Toast.makeText(this, "you are already signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                    Utils.LOGD(" mConnectionResult before trying to connect = " + mConnectionResult);
                    if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                try {


                    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(LoginActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);

                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Utils.LOGD( "Exception caught : ) " +  e.getMessage()) ;
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }
```

**onActivityResult :**

```
       @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) {

                  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && !mPlusClient.isConnected()
                          && !mPlusClient.isConnecting()) {

                        // This time, connect should succeed.
                        mPlusClient.connect();

                        Utils.LOGD("onActivityResult : mConnectionResult AFTER  trying to connect = " + mConnectionResult);
                        Utils.LOGD(" onActivityResult result code   = " + resultCode);
                     
                  }
            }
      }
```

The problem is after I click the sign in button and Google's built in  "loading.." progress bar shows, the app suddenly quits to the phone's main screen, without any error showing on the device itself NOR the in the logcat!

Also, when I come back to the app after it crashed, I see that the sign-in has finished successfully, onConnected has been called,  and I am logged in with my Google account.
(I have an editText showing my name after sign in)

This happens almost every time I click the button ' but not always.
I've also noticed that when running the app on an emulator this crash almost never happens. (though it happened few times )

I also added logs to see when onConnected onStop and onDestroy are called

here is the logcat from when I click sign-in, to immediately after the crash:

```
12-04 17:54:37.464    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕ onClick - View = com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton@415ea1f8
12-04 17:54:37.464    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕  onClick  : mPlusClient status  = com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient@41570e18
12-04 17:54:37.468    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕  mConnectionResult before trying to connect = ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{4164c2a8: android.os.BinderProxy@41571528}}
12-04 17:54:37.472    195-360/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START {cmp=com.google.android.gms/.plus.activity.AccountSignUpActivity (has extras)} from pid -1
12-04 17:54:37.550    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕ onPause
12-04 17:54:37.550    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕  onPause:   mPlusClient.isConnected   = false
12-04 17:54:37.550    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕     onPause: mPlusClient.isConnecting   = false
12-04 17:54:37.589    195-441/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START {act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.account.AccountPickerActivity (has extras)} from pid 6544
12-04 17:54:37.789    195-197/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 816K, 25% free 13321K/17671K, paused 10ms+11ms
12-04 17:54:37.793    195-227/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.google.android.gms/.plus.activity.AccountSignUpActivity: +235ms
12-04 17:54:37.937    1199-1210/com.google.android.gsf.login D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 144K, 7% free 9315K/9927K, paused 1ms+4ms
12-04 17:54:38.187    6544-6546/com.google.android.gms.ui D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 267K, 4% free 9530K/9927K, paused 2ms+16ms
12-04 17:54:38.211    195-3148/system_process W/InputManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@415115c8
12-04 17:54:38.312    631-634/com.google.android.gms D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 530K, 8% free 10775K/11591K, paused 2ms+15ms
12-04 17:54:38.351    6544-6544/com.google.android.gms.ui D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-04 17:54:38.371    6544-6544/com.google.android.gms.ui D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-04 17:54:38.375    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕ onStop
12-04 17:54:38.375    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕ onDestroy
12-04 17:54:38.418    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 1)
```

and this is the logcat after returning to the app

```
   12-04 17:59:21.828  195-441/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.meeba.google/.activities.LoginActivity bnds=[240,405][360,556]} from pid 406
12-04 17:59:21.988    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕  mPlusClient = :com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient@416af6d8
12-04 17:59:21.992    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕ onCreate finished
12-04 17:59:21.996    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕ onStart
12-04 17:59:22.003    406-406/com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 1)
12-04 17:59:22.019    6516-6518/com.meeba.google D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 406K, 5% free 12419K/12999K, paused 2ms+4ms
12-04 17:59:22.019    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕ onResume
12-04 17:59:22.078    406-406/com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-04 17:59:22.230    195-209/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 780K, 25% free 13351K/17671K, paused 3ms+12ms
12-04 17:59:22.355    631-634/com.google.android.gms D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 524K, 8% free 10777K/11591K, paused 3ms+4ms
12-04 17:59:22.378    195-209/system_process I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 6516 SIG: 3
12-04 17:59:22.378    6516-6520/com.meeba.google I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-04 17:59:22.382    6516-6520/com.meeba.google I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-04 17:59:22.429    195-227/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.meeba.google/.activities.LoginActivity: +553ms
12-04 17:59:22.640    6544-6544/com.google.android.gms.ui D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 1)
12-04 17:59:22.660    631-711/com.google.android.gms I/qtaguid﹕ Failed write_ctrl(u 90) res=-1 errno=22
12-04 17:59:22.683    6544-6546/com.google.android.gms.ui D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 458K, 7% free 9478K/10119K, paused 1ms+3ms
12-04 17:59:22.683    631-711/com.google.android.gms I/qtaguid﹕ Untagging socket 90 failed errno=-22
12-04 17:59:22.683    631-711/com.google.android.gms W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ untagSocket(90) failed with errno -22
12-04 17:59:22.707    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕  onConnected started
12-04 17:59:22.707    6516-6516/com.meeba.google D/debug﹕ mPlusClient in onConnected is =com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient@416af6d8
```

After debugging I saw that the app crashes exactly at the line
mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(LoginActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)

What is wrong or what should I do?

edited: added the manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.meeba.google"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.meeba.google.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.meeba.google.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.meeba.google" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".GcmIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity

            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activities.DashboardActivity" >
            <!--intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter-->
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activities.WhereWhenActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ContactsActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.InvitationActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.EventPageActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you filtering the logcat? I doubt the app is crashing without something in the logcat. Never filter the logcat when you are troubleshooting!

Comment: added manifest.xml to post

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remove `android:noHistory="true"` from the `<activity>` definition of `LoginActivity` in your manifest. I'm pretty sure that the `noHistory` setting causes Android to finish the `LoginActivity` when it starts the Google+ signin activity. Since the activity is already finished, there won't be anything there to call `onActivityResult()` on. Your app isn't actually crashing, it is just done.

If you want to make sure that the user doesn't BACK into your `LoginActivity` you will have to solve that problem in another way (override `onBackPressed()` or something else).

Comment: This was a nasty and elusive bug that I also had. So, how could one avoid this issue and at the same time avoid having the login screen on the history?

Comment: @Acapulco You can't. But what you can do is just remember whether the user is logged in or not, and if the login screen gets resumed, it should just call `finish()` or whatever if the user is already logged in. Another method is to override `onBackPressed()` so that users cant BACK into the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to **android:noHistory="true"** is to override onBackPressed method of Activity B.

```
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000;
private long mBackPressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        // exiting app
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            finishAffinity();
        }
        else {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return;
    } else {
        showSnackBar(R.string.exit_app);
    }
    mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```