# android:noHistory="true" behavior but still catch OnActivityResult?

Tags: android

I have an app that shows the user a profile edit screen the first time he or she uses the app.  Within the edit profile activity, I need to allow the user to create a profile image capture an image or select from the gallery.

I want to be able to catch OnActivityResult, but once they are done with 
editing profile, I don't want this to be on the stack. Setting noHistory to true kills the activity and I can't catch the result.

I want this for first time:
splash screen----> edit profile ----> main menu.

When the user presses the back button from the main menu, I want the app to stop, not pop edit profile from the stack.

Any idea on how to set noHistory after I've gotten OnActivityResult?

Comment: My initial thought was overriding onBackPressed. [Something like this?][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9548207/2151902

Comment: i can't even catch that - I tried a bunch, tho :).   It's taken off the stack immediately with noHistory, so the code isn't running at that point.

Comment: In manifest after <activity add this: android:excludeFromRecents="true" this will terminate app when pressed home and back button on the device seems like the app had never opened

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) there is no way to get result in activity that is specified with "noHistory"

> In this case, onActivityResult() is never called if you start another
>   activity for a result from this activity.

You can try to achieve desire result by clearing existing stack like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

It should start new task based on `main menu` activity.