# I have to press back twice to exit my app

Tags: android, android-activity, back

I have tried everything I have been able to find online to stop this happening before someone suggests 'Just go google it'....

I will be explicit in case it is not clear enough, I do not want to have to click back twice when I am on the registration or login screen. Its like I have an Activity A the user never sees, A starts an intent to either B or C.

On B or C I do not want to click twice to exit the application.

I have an Activity that I want to be invisible to the user, its purpose is to check if the application has been registered, if it has it starts an intent to login Activity, if the app is not registered it starts an intent to registration activity. The issue that when on the login or registration screen I have to press back twice to exit the application.

If I do not call `finish()` in this Activity the back button takes me to the transparent Activity and I have to press back again, calling `finish()` means I don't go back to the transparent Activity but I do have to press back twice - which I don't want.

I already tried calling the `startActivityForResult()` example, but this doesn't have any effect.

The Activity is using the transparent theme as using the `NoDisplay` theme caused an exception, googling this seemed to imply an issue with the emulator and suggested fix was to use transparent.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.AppEntryPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The Activity doesn't do a lot at the moment, currently I am trying the code below but this also has no effect and I still have to press the back button twice.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(!"".equals(((GlobalData) this.getApplication()).password)) {
        navigateToLoginScreen();
    } else {
        registerApplication();
    }
}


private void registerApplication() {
    Intent registerScreen = new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class);
    registerScreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(registerScreen);
    finish();
}

private void navigateToLoginScreen() {
    Intent loginScreen = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    loginScreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(loginScreen);
    finish();
}
```

What can I do to make sure that the user only has to press back once when they get to the second screen, whether it is the login or the registration screen?

Comment: I want when I click back to not have to press it twice?

Comment: This is because your main Activity is the "transparent" one. Why don't you use a service, instead?

Comment: Ok thanks so that isn't possible to do? I will look at services, I haven't used a service yet, I am replicating an IOS app and it just have a view controller which does the same thing.

Comment: I take it the main activity has to remain for the lifetime of the application?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried the solution below and it does work but I am not sure this is actually the best thing to do, I will have a read around creating a service to see how that would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack) will solve your problem.

just add `android:noHistory="true"` in the manifest file to your first activity, like this:

```
<activity
  android:name=".activity.AppEntryPoint"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:noHistory="true"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```