# While press back Button splash screen exits and opens Authentication Activity

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-lifecycle

I created two Activities "SplashActivity and AuthenticationActivity" When I start the app it loads the splash screen for 5 seconds and then it moves on to `AuthenticationActivity`. My problem is that when I run the app, it loads the splash screen, but within 5 seconds when I click the back button, `SplashActivity` exits, and immediately `AuthenticationActivity` appears in the foreground.
Does anyone know how to make it so when I click the back button, my app exits?

Here's my code so far:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    Thread splashTimer = new Thread(){


        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,AuthenticationActivity.class));
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                finish();
            }
        }

    };
    splashTimer.start();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}}
```

Comment: dont use thread use handler

Comment: remove super.onBackPressed();
from onbackpress method it will disable back press

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing an activity from the history stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize()
{
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //Start your activity here
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(timerTask,2500);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    timer.cancel();
}
```

or you can use Handler also

```
  Handler handler;
  Runnable runnable;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    initialize();
 }

private void initialize()
{
   handler = new Handler();
  runnable = new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    //start your activity here
                }
            };
   handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
   }

 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
     handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
 }
```

Comment: can anyone help me how to code using Handler and Runnable in my splashScreen