# Removing Android Activity from stack using nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

This post explains exactly what I want to do but I'm looking for help on how to do it in NativeScript.

[Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

**[Resolved]** I found the answer here:

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/ng-sample/app/examples/router/clear-history-test.ts

Comment: please add code.. what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code solution I came to using angular and nativescript:

```
// Sign In Page
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";

constructor(private _router: RouterExtensions) {}

private onSignInComplete(): void {
    this._router.navigate(["/mainPage"], { clearHistory: true });
}
```