# How can I not return to a previous activity after using startActivity?

Tags: android, android-intent

Assuming I have three activities with Android Studio:

Act_A

Act_B

Act_C

The Act_A calls Act_B, and Act_B calls Act_C:

```js
Intent intent = new Intent(Act_A.class,Act_B.class);
startActivity(intent);

...

Intent intent = new Intent(Act_B.class,Act_C.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Act_C a process is executed in which it should automatically be returned to Act_B, for which something similar is done:

```js
Intent intent = new Intent(Act_C.class,Act_B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

At this point, if the user presses the return button, it should be returned to Act_A, but it happens to be returned to Act_C, if you press once again the return button returns to Act_B.

My questions are:

Is there a way to "delete" the previous state so that it doesn't return to the previous activity or is there a way to modify it to return to the activity that I want?

The problem is that I have to return a value from Act_C to Act_B and I can not use finish(), something similar to the following:

In Act_C:

Intent intent = Act_B.newIntent(getActivity(),5);// return 5

startActivity(intent);

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer your question however you can block history alltogether in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [customize the back stack](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) of your activity if you really need to, but in this case it seems that what you want is just to go **back** to B from C, instead of starting B from C.

In other words, in order to accomplish "In Act_C a process is executed in which it should automatically be returned to Act_B", do the following instead of `startActivity()`:

```
    super.onBackPressed();
```

This will return the app to Act_B. Then if the user presses the back button, they will return to Act_A as you specified.

Comment: Assuming I have enabled the use of menus:

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)

In the menu there is a button with a return arrow, what is the event associated with it?

Comment: @FabiánRomo: In general, it's the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method that you need to override (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu). Beyond that, it's hard to tell much without seeing your code. You may have to create a new question and show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `finish()` method of an `Activity`. It will get you back to Activity_B while you are in Activity_C

Comment: The problem is that I have to return a value from Act_C to Act_B and I can not use finish, something similar to the following:

Intent intent = Act_B.newIntent(getActivity(),5);// return 5
startActivity(intent);

Comment: the you need to use `startActivityForResult()` to open Act_C from Act_B

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can either call finish() on your activity, use the noHistory flag for the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or add the intent flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY to your intent.

This post should help you out: [Removing an activity from the history stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

Answer (score 0):

*In Act_C a process is executed in which it should automatically be returned to Act_B*

If you just want to return a value from a specific activity don't use startActivity(Intent), use startActivityForResult(Intent, int) and deal with the return values on the callback (OnActivityResult). Then overwrite the onFinish() method so that you can setResult() upon exit.
I can give you more context on this if you need.